# Update large batches of tweets

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have over 750k tweets. These tweets are stored in a local MongoDB instance. I would like to create timestamps of each tweet using the following code. These timestamps are utilized later in other scripts.

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import time
import gc
gc.collect()

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:27017")
db = client.copySB #Database
col = db.original_tweets #Collectiion

start_time_total = time.time()

if col.find({"timestamp":{"$exists":False}}):
    for tweet in col.find({"timestamp":{"$exists":False}}):
        try:
            # loop_start_time = time.time()
            tweetId = tweet['id']
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
            epoch = date.utcfromtimestamp(0)
            timestamp = (date-epoch).total_seconds()
            col.update_one(          {'id': tweetId},
                                     #set - add item to the existing set, if not exist, will create a new field
                                     {'$set': {'timestamp': timestamp }},
                                     upsert=False
                                     )
            # loop_end_time = (time.time()-loop_start_time)/60
            # print("----------------------------------------------------")
            # print(f'Mongo data update loop took {loop_end_time} seconds')
            # print ("Total tweets altered in this loop")
            print(len(tweet))
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            pass
else:
    pass
end_time_total = (time.time()-start_time_total)/60
print("-----------------------------------")
print(f'Mongo data update took {end_time_total} minutes')
print ("total tweets in the dataset ")
print (col.estimated_document_count())
print ("total valid tweets with timestamp ")
print (col.count_documents({'timestamp' : {'$exists': True}}))
print("-----------------------------------")
```

This code works fine for what I need, but it iterates slowly. I am seeing my script only gather 30 tweets or so in each query. I've been running it all afternoon and it has only updated 150k tweets.

Why is my loop only gathering such a small amount of tweets? I have not specified any limits, but the script is only gathering small amounts each loop.

I would like to see my loop iterate through a batch size, but I am unsure how best to implement this. Suggestions?

**EDIT**: 
Now that I am near 300k altered tweets, the update process has slowed dramatically. From what I understand, is the script checking through every tweet in the collection before updating the next value?

**EDIT-2**:
After utilizing the solution from @BellyBuster, I was able to speedily update my tweets. Now I am curious as to what is best in terms of timestamping. My original code creates this timestamp, 1549250444. While the new code creates this timestamp, 1549248971000. The difference in these values makes me curious as to why the new method is creating a shorter timestamp.

**Final-Edit**:

My final command:

```
col.update_many({"timestamp": {"$exists": False}},
                [{'$addFields':
                        {'timestamp':
                            {'$divide':
                               [
                                {'$toLong':
                                    {'$toDate': '$created_at'}
                                },
                                1000
                               ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
               )
```

**My original question was not truly answered**, but this solution is more robust and operates quite well.

Comment: why don't you just try mongodb raw query?

Comment: @Alok this is for a more broad script that gathers the tweets from the twitter API. This is only a small section of that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have mongo 4.2 or greater you can do this in one aggregate command using the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) and [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html) operators; this takes less than one minute on my stock laptop for 750k records.

I would recommend storing date/times as ISODates not timestamps, but that is another matter.

ISODate version:

```
col.update_many({"timestamp": {"$exists": False}},
                          [{'$addFields': {'timestamp': {'$toDate': '$created_at'}}}])
```

Timestamp version:

```
col.update_many({"timestamp": {"$exists": False}},
                [{'$addFields': {'timestamp': {'$toLong': {'$toDate': '$created_at'}}}}])
```

Full worked example with data setup:

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import time
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
col = db.original_tweets  # Collectiion

operations = []

# Data Setup Only
for i in range(750000):
    operations.append(pymongo.InsertOne(
        {'created_at': datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')}))
col.bulk_write(operations)

# Update each record without a timestamp from the created_at field
start_time_total = time.time()

col.update_many({"timestamp": {"$exists": False}},
                [{'$addFields': {'timestamp': {'$toLong': {'$toDate': '$created_at'}}}}])

# Output

end_time_total = (time.time() - start_time_total) / 60
print("-----------------------------------")
print(f'Mongo data update took {end_time_total} minutes')
print("total tweets in the dataset ")
print(col.estimated_document_count())
print("total valid tweets with timestamp ")
print(col.count_documents({'timestamp': {'$exists': True}}))
print("-----------------------------------")

print(dumps(col.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

Gives:

```
-----------------------------------
Mongo data update took 0.4217496275901794 minutes
total tweets in the dataset 
750000
total valid tweets with timestamp 
750000
-----------------------------------
{
    "created_at": "Sun Dec 22 12:19:48 +0000 2019",
    "timestamp": 1577017188000
}
```

Comment: Super simple solution. I suppose operating on MongoDB's strengths is a wise choice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain how the timestamp is being created here?

Comment: see the documentation on `$to_date` linked. It is "Positive number corresponds to the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970." You might need to use a `$divide` if you still want seconds.

Comment: try bulk update for updating large documents
var bulkOp = db.col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulkOp.find({}).update({'$addFields':{'timestamp':{'$divide':[{'$toLong': {'$toDate': '$created_at'} },1000]} }});

bulkOp.execute();